# Check if in string are number after number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string 123aSdfghjk. How can i check if in string number after number. 
I want to create function who return false if string who have number after number.
Like this.

I want to this string return false: 468rVrgywjo, and true for eg. asd3fGhjk

Because I want to check if string which I pass through the function parameter have number after number.

Comment: please add your approach.

Comment: a good regexp can be an idea, but you have to start with that on your own and come here with what you have done

Comment: You could check for match of a pattern: `\d{2,}` - 2 or more digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with *RegEx* checking whether the string starts with number or not:

```js
function checkString(str){
  return /^[^\d+].*$/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkString('468rVrgywjo'));
console.log(checkString('asd3fGhjk'));
```

**Update:** It seems like I missed the point *I want to create function who return false if string who have number after number.*

```js
function checkString(str){
  return !/\d{2}/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkString('468rVrgywjo'));
console.log(checkString('asd3fGhjk'));
```

Comment: what has the answer to do with the question?

Comment: @NGrdanjski, I missed some part of the question, please notice the update in the question:)

Comment: this really unfair. you wrote somthing different answer then you copied the right answer. anyway.

Comment: @NinaScholz, so according to you correcting answer is unfair!!! I have also learnt the new meaning of *copy* from you(:

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a number follows by a number and return the opposite result of the check.

```js
function checkString(str){
    return !/\d\d/.test(str);
}

console.log(checkString('468rVrgywjo'));
console.log(checkString('a468rVrgywjo'));
console.log(checkString('asd3fGhjk'));
```